# Length of Python dictionary created doesn't match length from input file

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, diskspace, mismatch

I'm currently trying to create a dictionary from the following input file:

```
1776344_at      1779734_at  0.755332745 1.009570769 -0.497209846
1776344_at      1771911_at  0.931592828 0.830039019 2.28101445
1776344_at      1777458_at  0.746306282 0.753624146 3.709120716
...
...
```

There are a total of 12552 lines in this file.

What I wanted to do is to create a dictionary where the first 2 columns are the keys and the rest are the values. This I've successfully done and it looks something like this:

```
1770449_s_at;1777263_at:0.825723773;1.188969175;-2.858979578
1772892_at;1772051_at:-0.743866602;-1.303847456;26.41464414
1777227_at;1779218_s_at:0.819554413;0.677758609;4.51390617
```

But here's THE THING: I ran my python script on ms-dos cmd, and the generated output not only does not have the same sequence as that in the input file (i.e. 1st line is the 34th line), the whole file only has 739 lines.

Can someone enlighten me on what's going on? Is it something to do with memory? Cos the last I check I still have 305GB of disk space.

The **script** I wrote is as follow:

```
import sys
import os

input_file = sys.argv[1]
infile = open(input_file, 'r')

model_dict = {}
for line in infile:
    key = ';'.join(line.split('\t')[0:2]).rstrip(os.linesep)
    value = ';'.join(line.split('\t')[2:]).rstrip(os.linesep)
    print 'keys are:',key,'\n','values are:',value
    model_dict[key] = value
    print model_dict
    outfile = open('model_dict', 'w')
    for key,value in model_dict.items():
        print key,value
        outfile.write('%s:%s\n' % (key,value))

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given and since each dictionary key is unique, i suspect you have in the input file, lines that are generating the same key. This way the dictionary will only hold the last value associated with that key.

Python dictionaries are unordered set of key: value pairs. So when you print it's elements to the output file, don't expect that the order is preserved.

Another problem i see in your script is the loop that prints the output file, that shouldn't be "inside" the loop that reads from the input file.

Comment: Hi dethos! Thank you very much, I tried editing my script with your advice and it ran successfully with the correct number of lines in the output.

Comment: Good, glad i could help!